# How can I check if a value is 0 in Excel? (If there are blank cells in the same column)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table on Excel, and there is column B which contains numbers (from 0 to 240) but it also contains blanks.

I have a code that looks something like thhis

```
for i = 2 to 500

My_Value = Worksheets("MachineData").range("B" & i).value

if My_Value = 0 then
'Do Something
end if

next i
```

The problem with this is that Excel thinks that blank cells are also 0. so how can I check for when the value of the cell is 0 and only 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should check for the value being zero, combined with the length of that value, being one. (Length zero means that nothing is filled in)

In code: (not tested)

```
if ((My_Value = 0) And Len(My_Value) = 1) then
```

Comment: `IsEmpty` is another option, instead of `Len`.